# 1064 MySQL error in decrement using

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm using `Update videos Set views = views + 1 Where video_id='$id'`, but MySQL give me back error 1064:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ' 8' at line 1

What can cause it?

Comment: what the datatype of column "views" ?

Comment: What data type is your `video_id` column? Did you try echoing or printing the statement after you concatenate the `$id` to it to see if it's right? It looks like you're missing quotes around a string column, but you didn't provide enough information to tell for sure. (Also, there's no "decrement" either in your post or your code; you're **incrementing** a column value by increasing it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely $id is not what you expect it is.  I imagine the query that is coming through looks something like

```
update videos set view = views + 1 where video='' 8'';
```

Note: Those are two single quotes on either side of the 8.

To confirm this you have a couple options.

- Turn on general query logging, as a super user (root) from the mysql command prompt run

  set general_log_file='/tmp/mysql.log';
  set general_log ='on';

Now every single query that gets sent to mysql will show up in /tmp/mysql.log  (Note this can quickly grow very large so don't leave it on after you're done debugging).

- App logs

Do you have any kind of logging frame work going on?  Before your actual call to execute the query, log the value of ($id).  For a poor mans logging you could do something like

file_put_contents('/tmp/debug.txt', date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." id is [$id]\n",FILE_APPEND);